# incremental gaussian mixture model

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have trained GMM on small train data set, I would like to update the GMM parameters on the fly when new samples arrive. Please direct on how to do that? Please inform if some existing implementation exits in python

dataset is speech utterance, and I would like to update the parameters of the model of a speaker, as new utterances are added instead of re-training with the entire data.

Comment: Can you give more details about the model you are using and the data-set?

Comment: details are added. Please provide suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about an incremental Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) training: [Song and Wang, 2005](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.1698&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

The authors derive formulas for updating the GMM when a new batch of data arrives. Their formulas are interesting in the sense that only newly arrived data is needed to update GMM parameters.

For each new batch, they use covariance and Hotelling's $T^2$ tests to decide if it is needed to merge equivalent clusters.

Comment: thanks for the article! Are you aware of any existing implementation for this ?

Comment: No, I don't know any. Hope it will help you anyway